# Unprivileged lxc container as root

Tags: lxc

I have successfully been able to run privileged lxc containers (as root).
My system:

```
uname -a
Linux ruby-dev 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo apt-get install cgmanager cgmanager-utils cgroup-bin

The following are available on system: libcap, libapparmor, libselinux, libseccomp, pyhton3-dev

sudo apt-get install lxc
sudo lxc-create -t download -n semiprivcont1 -- -d ubuntu -r trusty -a amd64
sudo lxc-start -n semiprivcont1 -d
```

This starts the semiprivcont1

```
lxc-ls -f
NAME           STATE    IPV4       IPV6  AUTOSTART  
--------------------------------------------------
semiprivcont1      RUNNING  10.0.3.99  -     NO
```

Now I stopped the container using `lxc-stop`.

Created a user lxchostuser. (`sudo adduser lxchostuser`)

```
cat /etc/subuid
lxchostuser:165536:65536

cat /etc/subgid
lxchostuser:165536:65536

vi /var/lib/lxc/semiprivcont1/config
```

added the following lines:

```
lxc.id_map = u 0 165536 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 165536 65536
```

Now trying to start semiprivcont1:

```
sudo lxc-start -n semiprivcont1 -d

lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 342 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 344 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 346 Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile

sudo lxc-start -n semiprivcont1 -d --logfile semiprivcont1.log --logpriority=DEBUG

lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 342 The container failed to start.
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 344 To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
```

As seen in the log semiprivcont1.log, the container is having errors with the id mappings introduced in the config file.

```
lxc-start 1427506372.212 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4735 - Error setting up child mappings
      lxc-start 1427506372.212 ERROR    lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:chown_cgroup:485 - Error requesting cgroup chown in new namespace
      lxc-start 1427506372.212 WARN     lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:cgm_chown:1266 - Failed to chown lxc/semiprivcont1 to container root
      lxc-start 1427506372.219 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_assign_network:3420 - move '(null)' to '17213'
      lxc-start 1427506372.242 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:955 - failed to set up id mapping
      lxc-start 1427506372.242 WARN     lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_delete_network:3296 - failed to remove interface '(null)'
      lxc-start 1427506372.243 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1080 - failed to spawn 'semiprivcont1'
      lxc-start 1427506372.243 WARN     lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:172 - command get_init_pid failed to receive response
      lxc-start 1427506372.243 WARN     lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:cgm_get:954 - do_cgm_get exited with error
      lxc-start 1427506377.250 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:342 - The container failed to start.
      lxc-start 1427506377.250 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:344 - To get more
```

Any pointers/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When trying to do the same, I had the log line: `Permission denied - could not access /var/lib/lxc.  Please grant it 'x' access, or add an ACL for the container root.`. `chmod +x /var/lib/lxc/` solved it for me. And instead of `lxchostuser:165536:65536` I had `root:165536:65536` in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`